# Create new model with the same object odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I want to create a function when I click it copies all the information in a new model itself and it changes the values of field  **type** to > *exp* if the state is 'accepted' or 'success';

```
class Studenttest(models.Model):
    _name = 'student.test'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']


def copy_result(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
    if not default:
        default = {} 
    if self.state == 'accepted' or self.state == 'success':
        default.update({
            'type'== 'exp'
        })
    return super(StudentExam, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)


student_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Student", required=True)
state = fields.Selection([ ('accepted', 'Accepted'), ('success', 'Success'),('not_pass', 'Not Pass'))], string='State', default='no_date')
type = fields.Selection([('exp', 'Exp'), ('main', 'Main')], string='Type') 
user_id= fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Student", required=True)
```

I do not know what is possible with **write** or **create**

Answer (score 1):

This method(old api) is deprecated in odoo version 11.

You can refer the pos order return function from odoo-11.0/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_order.py

Search for the function named `def refund(self):` 
which Create a copy of order  for refund order